# "invalid use of non static member function" What is this?

Tags: c++, class, function, syntax

EDIT: thanks for all the speedy responses, I have a much better understanding of this concept now. Also, I'll try to make my error messages more clear next time.
EDIT: updated with my newest code. the error happens on line 18. Also, I'm beginning to wonder if my latest issue has to do with the original class itself?

I'm trying to teach myself classes and objects in C++. I did it once by just declaring a `void` function, outputting something on the screen, calling the object in main and everything worked fine.

Now, I wanted to expand upon this and make a simple addition thing. However, I get a couple errors on Code Blocks:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function 'int Addition::add(int, int)'
error: no matching function for call to 'Addition::add()'
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Addition {
public:
int add (int x, int y) {
int sum;
sum=x+y;
return sum;
}
};

int main()
{
int num1;
int num2;
int ans=addobj.add(num1,num2);
Addition addobj;
addobj.add(num1,num2);
cout<<"Enter the first number you want to add"<<endl;
cin>>num1;
cout<<"Enter the second number you want to add"<<endl;
cin>>num2;
cout<<"The sum is "<<ans<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The first error does not apply to the code above. When posting compilation errors, make sure to post the exact code, the exact error code and an indication of the line where the compiler is complaining. (BTW, the first error message looks like you tried to do `Addition::add` somewhere in your code outside of a member of `Addition`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the most important things, a developer should learn to do is to read compiler's messages. It's clear enough:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Addition::add()'
```

Your function in your class is

```
int add (int x, int y)
```

it takes 2 arguments and you pass none:

```
addobj.add();
```

---

You have 2 options:

- create and initialize `x` and `y` inside your `main` and pass them as arguments
- make `add` without parameters, create `x` and `y` inside `add`'s body, as their values are taken from user input.

In this case, as the function's name is `add`, I'd chose the first option:

- declare `int x, y;` inside your `main`
- read the user input inside the `main` (the part, where you use `cin` and `cout`)
- pass the `x` and `y` as arguments to `add` like this: `addobj.add( x, y );`
- store the result (if needed), like this: `int result = addobj.add( x, y );`

Comment: Hey Kiril, thanks for the comprehensive answer, I was able to figure out what's wrong from my original problem. However, I am not able to get the result thing working properly. I created an integer "ans" in my main and set it equal to addobj.add(num1, num2). Then in another cout, I tried to display "int result." However, I got yet another error. Tried my best to figure out what's wrong, but alas didn't find the error. It says "addobj was not declared in the scope" pointing to the line where I set it equal to the answer integer. As you can see I have clearly specified Addition addobj.

Comment: @Carpetfizz - you need to define `addobj` before using it. Watching your edit, move the line `Addition addobj;` before `int ans=addobj.add(num1,num2);`. Then, to get the **correct** result, first you **must** initialize the `num1` and `num2`, before passing them as arguments. In other words, move the line `int ans=addobj.add(num1,num2);` **after** the last `cin`. And the last thing - `addobj.add(num1,num2);` is unnecessary - you have two calls of `add` - one, that you store the result and this one. Remove this one, leave the one with storing the `ans`.

Comment: Wow thank you sooo much!!! Worked perfectly! This is great, I'll practice some more with classes so that I can do the things you told in my first time around! Thanks again Kiril, and also everyone else who helped me out :)

Answer (score 4):

You declared a method `add(int, int)` that takes two integers as arguments; you have to supply those arguments when you call it. It would be nice to print the returned value, as well:

```
Addition addobj;
std::cout << addobj.add(1, 2) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `add` function takes two arguments, yet you call it with none, so no matching function could be found.  You must call the function as it was declared, i.e.,

```
addobj.add(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function takes two arguments and yet you call it without providing them. You need to provide the two integer arguments that your function requires. To be useful you should store the result too. Something like this

```
 int a = 1;
 int b = 2;
 int result = addjobs.add(a,b);
```